# Ratio of two independent Gamma distributions

Tags: distributions, gamma-distribution

### Pre-requisites

I have seen in Wikipedia that it says for independent r.v. $X \sim G(m), Y \sim G(n)$ the ratio $X/Y \sim B'(m,n)$.

Where $G(x)$ denotes the standard Gamma distribution
$$ f(x,\lambda)= \begin{cases} 
\frac{e^{-x} x^{\lambda -1}}{\Gamma (\lambda )} & x>0, \lambda >0\\
  0 &\text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$$

and $B'(m,n)$ denotes the Beta prime distribution,
$$ f(x,m,n)=\begin{cases}
  \frac{1}{\beta(m,n)}\frac{x^{m-1}}{(1+x)^{m+n}} & x,m,n>0\\
  0 & \text{otherwise}
 \end{cases} $$

### Question

How can I prove the fact that for independent r.v. $X,Y$ such that $X \sim G(m), Y \sim G(n)$ the ratio $X/Y \sim B'(m,n)$.

I have seen the statement in questions here too ([distribution of the ratio of two gamma random variables](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/207595/distribution-of-the-ratio-of-two-gamma-random-variables)) but not the complete proof.

### My attempt

I attempted to find the distribution of $X/Y$ by just multiply the pdfs of $X, 1/Y$ since they are independent to get the distribution of $X/Y$.

I believe there must be some fundamental flaw here since this doesn't work. I am writing it out for completeness sake but would greatly appreciate someone telling me what I am doing wrong.

---

Let $u=1/y$ it's range is $[0,\infty)$ and its Jacobian $|J|$ is given by $\frac{1}{u^2}$. Using this we compute the pdf of $u$ as
\begin{align}
h(u)&=f(y) |J|\\
&=\frac{e^{-y}y^{n-1}}{\Gamma(n)} |J|\\
&\text{Substituting $y=1/u$}\\
&= \frac{e^{-1/u}(1/u)^{n-1}}{\Gamma(n)}\frac{1}{u^2}\\
&=\frac{e^{-1/u}u^{-(n+1)}}{\Gamma(n)}
\end{align}
So as expected $U=1/Y$ follows the [Inverse-Gamma distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse-gamma_distribution).

But now if we compute the joint distribution of $X \cdot U=X/Y$ we get what is basically just the product of Gamma distribution and inverse-gamma distribution. This isn't the Beta prime distribution.

This product does seem to be a valid joint pdf since its double integral evaluates to 1 but it isn't the ratio distribution that was desired.

I'm afraid the joint distribution $X \cdot U$ isn't actually the ratio distribution. Could someone please explain where my reasoning is wrong? And what the correct method to prove this is?

Comment: The joint distribution of $(X,U)$ is not the distribution of $X \times U$. You need another change of variable, for instance into $(X,V=X \times U)$ and a marginalisation in $U$, integrating out $X$.

Comment: The PDF of a ratio or product is *not* the ratio or product of the PDFs.  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ratio_distribution#Derivation for instance.

Comment: Using the ratio distribution in the above link, you can reduce the integral using the gamma function and the change of variables $v=y(1+z)$.